# How to save automatically allocated memory block after program execution in c?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management, casting

I have a struct :

```
typedef struct myd_tag{
   char *first;
   char *last;
}myd;
```

I cast this struct to (char*) and insert it into a database(gdbm).

```
data2.dptr = (char*)&d2;
```

I allocate memory with malloc for 'first' and 'last' and I do not free them. However after the program execution, the memory blocks are disappeared and I can't reach the data in first and last after I fetched them from database. When I do the same thing with the statically allocated variables as shown below, I can reach the data in them after i fetched from the database.

```
typedef struct myd_tag{
    char first[24];
    char last[24];
}myd;
```

Is there a way to save the memory blocks which are taken with dynamic allocation, after program execution?

Here is the full code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gdbm.h>

typedef struct myd_tag{

char *first;
char *last;
}myd;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GDBM_FILE myfile;
myd d2;

datum key1, data1, ndata1;
datum key2, data2, ndata2;

char *k1 = "msg1";
char *d1 = "I love C programming.";

char *k2 = "msg2";

d2.first=malloc(strlen("John") + 1);
d2.last = malloc(strlen("Doe") + 1);

strcpy(d2.first,"John");
strcpy(d2.last,"Doe");

key1.dptr = k1;
key1.dsize = strlen(k1) + 1;

data1.dptr = d1;
data1.dsize = strlen(d1) + 1;

key2.dptr = k2;
key2.dsize = strlen(k2) + 1;    

data2.dptr = (char*)&d2;
data2.dsize = sizeof(d2);

myfile = gdbm_open("mydatabase", 0, GDBM_WRCREAT | GDBM_READER, 0660, 0);

gdbm_store(myfile, key1, data1, GDBM_INSERT);
gdbm_store(myfile, key2, data2, GDBM_INSERT);

ndata1 = gdbm_fetch(myfile, key1);
ndata2 = gdbm_fetch(myfile, key2);

printf("ndata1: %s\n", ndata1.dptr);
printf("ndata2: %s\n", ((myd*)ndata2.dptr)->first);
printf("ndata2: %s\n", ((myd*)ndata2.dptr)->last);

gdbm_close(myfile);
return 0;
}
```

When I executed the program, ndata2 is fetched good and i can reach the data. However after this program I run a test program to see if the data is still available.
Here is the test program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gdbm.h>

typedef struct myd_tag{
char *first;
char *last;
}myd;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
GDBM_FILE myfile;

datum key1, data1, ndata1;

myfile = gdbm_open("mydatabase", 0, GDBM_WRCREAT | GDBM_READER, 0660, 0);

key1 = gdbm_firstkey(myfile);
data1 = gdbm_fetch(myfile, key1);

printf("key: %s data : %s\n", key1.dptr, ((myd*)(data1.dptr))->first);


gdbm_close(myfile);
return 0;
}
```

When I run test program, key1.dptr is read correctly however when I try to reach data1.dptr I get a Segmentation Fault error.

Comment: Please show your code. As a [mcve]. How can we possibly tell you what you have done wrong without that?

Comment: Perhaps store them in the database...?

Comment: data2.first and data2.last are pointers... They show an address in memory where "John" and "Doe" are stored.  The "addresses" are stored in the database, NOT what they point to.  When the first  program exits, those addresses are no longer valid, as the memory is released. When the second program retrieves data2 from the database, data2.first and data2.last contain pointers to addresses that were released and are (probably) invalid, but in all cases does not point to "John" or "Doe".

Comment: @TonyB yes I exactly understand it, however i call malloc. I want these memory block to be alive until I "intentionally" free them.

Comment: When your program exits, the malloc'd memory is automatically freed.  If you want memory to persist after the first program exits, then you should use "Shared Memory"... which is not allocated with "malloc".... and does not persist following a reboot and has other semantics for accessing it.  You  solution would be to statically size "first", and "last".